# Updating a git mirror of an SVN repository

Tags: git, git-svn

I created a git mirror of an SVN repository by doing:

- Create a new repo on github
- mkdir mirror && cd mirror
- git svn init [svn url]
- git svn fetch -rHEAD
- git remote add origin [github url]
- git svn rebase
- git push origin master

This works great, and I can update it with simply:

- git svn rebase
- git push origin master

However, if I move to a different computer and want to update it, I tried:

- git clone [github url]
- git svn init [svn url]
- git svn fetch -rHEAD
- git remote add origin [github url]
- git svn rebase

but here I get:

"Unable to determine upstream SVN information from working tree history"

Can anyone explain the correct way to do this?

Comment: in fact you can only push trunk branch of svn repo to git's master branch, the issue is how to push all svn branches to remote git repo?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the same need and eventually found an example here:

http://rip747.wordpress.com/2009/06/17/reviving-a-git-svn-clone/

To answer in the context of your question:

```
git clone [github url]
cd repo
git svn init [svn url]
git update-ref refs/remotes/git-svn refs/remotes/origin/master
git svn rebase
```

Comment: Hum I got an error "Unable to determine upstream SVN information from working tree history"

Comment: Solved by appending `/trunk` to the svn url

Comment: Instead of appending `/trunk` to the url, you can init the git svn repo with the standard layout, i.e. `-s` or `--stdlayout`.